# df disagrees with cfdisk and VirtualBox about partition size

Tags: virtualbox

To reproduce:

1. Create a new VM in the VirtualBox GUI with type "Linux" and version "Arch Linux (64-bit)". As part of this process create an 8 GB VDI disk with dynamic allocation and attach the latest Arch Linux ISO.
2. Boot into the Arch Linux ISO and set up the OS in the usual way.
3. Boot into the OS.
4. Fill up the disk.
5. Shut down the VM
6. Open the virtual media manager and change the size of the disk to a larger size (30 GB in my case).
7. Boot into the Arch Linux ISO.
8. Run `cfdisk /dev/sda` and change the partition size.
9. Write the partition table.
10. Reboot

At this point `fdisk -l` and `cfdisk /dev/sda` report /dev/sda1 as being 30 GB, while `df -h` reports it as 8 GB. I'm not able to write more to the disk.

Workarounds I've tried:

- Copying the disk image to another dynamically allocated VDI and attaching that instead.
- Copying the disk image to another dynamically allocated *VHD* and attaching that instead.
- Copying the disk image to another *statically* allocated VDI and attaching that instead.

[This problem](https://superuser.com/q/842921/2259) looks similar, except I've done all of this in only in VirtualBox without updating or rebooting the host OS.

Answer (score 0):

This worked:

1. Boot into the Arch Linux ISO.
2. Run `resize2fs /dev/sda1`

I *think* this resizes the *filesystem* as opposed to just the partition.

Comment: Might be helpful to elaborate a bit on why this needs to be done when resizing partitions.